# how to align UIControls in iphone Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-4.1

I m developing an appliaction, same application was developed in Android, In Android there is a concept called Layout. in that if any controls hidden that controls space will be occupied by near by controls and if the hidden control reappears, the near  by control will go back to its original position leaving space for the appeared control.Is there anything like that in iphone(xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such concept of layouts in iPhone like Android. You can place different controls manually using interface builder and use their alpha properties in order to show/hide them. If you want to make the controls' appearances dependent then you have to code it accordingly.